# Detaching logic from listener implementation in "Smart UI" approach to follow a proper pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, android, event-handling, gui

I took this code segment from existing source on Android, but it applies to anything from **ASP.NET Forms** to anything else where the UI has an *event callback*, and the logic is implemented *directly in that callback*. That's basically **"Smart UI"**, aka it is the GUI itself that knows how to execute the logic. This is simple to code, but hard to maintain and figure out what is what later, and cannot be properly reused easily.

In Android, this is often done as

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        //doStuff
    }
});
```

Or in this case with the following

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view)
{
    if(view == button)
    {
        //doStuff
    }
}
```

And this hardcodes the logic into the Activity or Fragment, and it is also part of the listener interface. This can create a mess such as the following:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    if (v == startDatePicker)
    {
        if (isDateDialogActive == false)
        {
            isDateDialogActive = true;
            activeSelectedDatePicker = startDatePicker;
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this,
                    calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            dialog.show();
        }
    }
    else if (v == endDatePicker)
    {
        if (isDateDialogActive == false)
        {
            isDateDialogActive = true;
            activeSelectedDatePicker = endDatePicker;
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this,
                    calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            dialog.show();
        }
    }
    else if (v == startTimePicker)
    {
        if (isTimeDialogActive == false)
        {
            TimePickerDialogFragment tpdf = new TimePickerDialogFragment();
            tpdf.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("set_hour", 0);
            bundle.putInt("set_minute", 0);
            tpdf.setArguments(bundle);
            activity_showDialog.showDialog(tpdf);
            isTimeDialogActive = true;
        }
    }
    else if (v == endTimePicker)
    {
        if (isTimeDialogActive == false)
        {
            TimePickerDialogFragment tpdf = new TimePickerDialogFragment();
            tpdf.setTargetFragment(this, 1);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("set_hour", 0);
            bundle.putInt("set_minute", 0);
            tpdf.setArguments(bundle);
            activity_showDialog.showDialog(tpdf);
            isTimeDialogActive = true;
        }
    }
    else if (v == typeInfoButton)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this.getActivity(), SearchDemoActivity.class);
        getActivity().startActivity(intent);
    }
    else if (v == saveButton)
    {
        if (!"".equals(this.endDate) && !"".equals(this.startDate) && !"".equals(this.startTime)
                && !"".equals(this.endTime) && comment != null
                && !"".equals(this.comment.toString()))
        {
            EventDataSource eventDataSource = new EventDataSource(getActivity()
                    .getApplicationContext());
            eventDataSource.open();
            eventDataSource.createEvent(type.getName(), startDate, endDate, startTime,
                    endTime, comment.toString(), EventDB.STATE_PENDING, 1);
            eventDataSource.close();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.event_created),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            getActivity().onBackPressed();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.please_specify_all_data), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is suboptimal for numerous reasons, mostly in terms of readability, extensibility, and most importantly the `start` and `end` quite obviously has code duplication and the only differing thing is the target code. And, the logic is not reusable at all, and is hidden inside the button listener implementation.

What would you do to detach this type of logic from the button's event handler?

Comment: I took the liberty to add the relevant language tags. Be aware that answers may address anything in your code, not just the design. For more information, read [Asking questions - getting the most value out of CodeReview](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer a mixed approach for situations like this, and a second problem is your code duplication. Let me describe the mixed approach:

You have a monolithic event handler, that handles the `onClick` for all `View` targets. Each of those events should be in a different function in your code. For example:

```
private void dateStartClicked() {
    if (isDateDialogActive == false)
    {
        isDateDialogActive = true;
        activeSelectedDatePicker = startDatePicker;
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this,
                calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Then, you should have an anonymous listener that handles just that one view, and it calls back to the non-anonymous handler:

```
dateStartPicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        dateStartClicked();
    }
});
```

Now, each button has their own listener. The anonymous classes have small code blocks. In Java8 (when that's supported) you can contract it further if you need using a FunctionalInterface call, something like:

```
dateStartPicker.setOnClickListener(() -> dateStartClicked());
```

Now, all your logic is isolated in to methods. All you need to do now is reduce the code duplication. The Date Picker is an obvious candidate. Both the start and end pickers use the same code, but with a different target `activeSelectedDatePicker`. You should extract that code in to a separate method that passes in the target active selector as a parameter.

Comment: That certainly sounds like a good way to start. Do you think it's reasonable to then grab these methods that are called, move them to new classes, and add these classes to the Activity using dependency injection? That's kinda what I'd do in a Spring environment, but Spring makes "autowiring" dependencies much easier as it's just three annotations.

Comment: Although I guess as long as you have only one possible implementation of the logic, you can "fake" dependency injection if you don't want to mess with a framework by just creating these at the start of an activity (even if that means hardcoding a dependency - at least it won't be the Activity that is responsible for the logic). I'm somewhat thinking out loud at the moment.